# How to disable ALL logs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our site is periodically slow. We use Azure Web Apps

We found out that we're having issues getting 404s/500s,etc and working to address this. Because of so many of the messages, we determined that the reporting of the messages is degrading response times.

Previously I disabled ALL messaging and our site's performance increased dramatically.

I recently deployed and the slow response is appearing again. I was able to disable the logs in App Services > Diagnostic Logs. Although, response is still slow.  Also, when I go to App Services > Overview I still see reporting of Http 500s, Requests, etc.

Is there a way to disable these messages as well; the basics metrics on App Services > Overview?  I'm assuming since these counts on this page, I missed disabling something and what could be causing our slowness

Answer (score 0):

The platform has a basic level of logging that cannot be turned off. This is to help ensure that support engineers have a 90 day historical view of activity on your app when troubleshooting issues. If you have every log turned off under 'Diagnostic Logs' then this is as far you can go.

Looking at the core issue, slow performance and 5XX errors, there are many items that could be causing this. Without having your site name, my advice would be to have you start using the 'diagnose and solve' blade for your web app. This is built upon a lot of the tooling that our support engineers use.

My advice would be to start with the long running/slow requests. See if the diagnose blade can pull the long running requests and it should hopefully give you additional details on where time is being spent to serve the request. Is it being spent on a particular module, lack of memory, etc.?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  As probably understand, this has been a difficult problem for us.

Comment: Initially I tried everything; App Insights, diagnose&solve, etc and can see sporadic long response times but not the culprit.  Although, the consistent thing is the 404s.  We assumed with so many 404s (we use Umbraco), it was probably causing issue with reporting these so turned of logging and site improved dramatically. But after deploying recently & disabling logs again, site continues to have sporadic long response times.  I don't recall what else I did.

Comment: Trach, finally remembered what I did last time; set level='off' in log4net config.   This was set to "info".  Guess we must have a lot of info and lower messaging. If it being set to 'info' and having dignostic logs off, where are these log written? Thanks

Comment: Gotcha, you are using Log4Net. Log4Net is a custom logging implementation. We typically suggest using Application Insights but we do support Log4Net if that's your preference. In this case, can you please check your web.config file to see where you have customized for the log files to be saved to? For more information on maximizing your usage of Log4Net, if you choose to enable it again, please see the below blog. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/09/27/how-to-configure-log4net-on-azure-app-service/